# Moving values between rows without a for loop in R

Tags: performance, r, for-loop, dataframe

I have written some code used to organize data sampled at different frequencies, but I made extensive use of for-loops, which slow the code's operation down significantly when the data set is large.  I've been going through my code, finding ways to remove for-loops to speed it up, but one of the loops has got me stumped.

As an example, let's say the data was sampled at 3Hz, so I get three rows for every second of data.  However, the variables A, B, and C are sampled at 1Hz each, so I will get one value every three rows for each of them. The variables are sampled consecutively within the one second period, resulting in a diagonal nature to the data.

To further complicate things, sometimes a row is lost in the original data set.

My goal is this: Having identified the rows that I wish to keep, I want to move the non-NA values from the subsequent rows up into the keeper rows. If it weren't for the lost data issue, I would always keep the row containing a value for the first variable, but if one of these rows is lost, I will be keeping the next row.

In the example below, the sixth sample and the tenth sample are lost.

```
A <- c(1, NA, NA, 4, NA, 7, NA, NA, NA, NA)
B <- c(NA, 2, NA, NA, 5, NA, 8, NA, 11, NA)
C <- c(NA, NA, 3, NA, NA, NA, NA, 9, NA, 12)

test_df <- data.frame(A = A, B = B, C = C)

test_df
     A  B  C
 1   1 NA NA
 2  NA  2 NA
 3  NA NA  3
 4   4 NA NA
 5  NA  5 NA
 6   7 NA NA
 7  NA  8 NA
 8  NA NA  9
 9  NA 11 NA
10  NA NA 12

keep_rows <- c(1, 4, 6, 9)
```

After I move the values up into the keeper rows, I will remove the interim rows, resulting in the following:

```
test_df <- test_df[keep_rows, ]
test_df
     A  B  C
 1   1  2  3
 2   4  5 NA
 3   7  8  9
 4  NA 11 12
```

In the end, I only want one row for each second of data, and NA values should only remain where a row of the original data was lost.

Does anyone have any ideas of how to move the data up without using a for-loop? I'd appreciate any help! Sorry if this question is too wordy; I wanted to err on the side of too much information rather than not enough.

Comment: To clarify: Can two or more consecutive rows be lost? If, say, instead of dropping 6 and 10, you dropped 4, 5, and 6, how would you detect that that had happened?

Comment: Yes, multiple consecutive rows can be lost.  I've identified which rows to keep after taking that into account elsewhere in my code, and I would have ended up with something like the "rows_to_keep" variable that I gave in my example being generated by the code instead of being user-defined. I'm not sure if that would cause an issue in the solutions given, since the "rows_to_keep" variable wasn't implemented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it:

```
test_df = with(test_df, cbind(A[1:(length(A)-2)], B[2:(length(B)-1)], C[3:length(C)]))
test_df = data.frame(test_df[!apply(test_df, 1, function(x) all(is.na(x))), ])
colnames(test_df) = c('A', 'B', 'C')
```

```or-tag-here
> test_df
   A  B  C
1  1  2  3
2  4  5 NA
3  7  8  9
4 NA 11 12
```

And if you want something even *faster*:

```
test_df = data.frame(test_df[rowSums(is.na(test_df)) != ncol(test_df), ])
```

Comment: The loop isn't a `for` but it's still a loop.

Comment: See edit. It's always going to be a loop, but at least this loop is all in C code.

Comment: It's not "always" going to be a loop. I'm certain there's a vectorized solution. I'll write it up tonight if nobody beats me to it.

Comment: @goodside Great I'd love to know if there is. The second method above takes only 50ms for 10^6 rows on my machine, but you can compare it to what you do on yours.

Comment: Thank you, John.  This solution works for me!  I need to get myself more familiar with the "with" and "apply" functions so I can come up with this type of answer myself.

Comment: much better John Colby... I was actually just about to post the same thing after realizing my magic number version was longer than necessary.  You should probably just edit out the apply version all together since it doesn't genuinely answer the question.

Comment: ...I updated my timings to include your update. It beats all the other methods! Great job!

Comment: Cool! I learned that trick from SO myself awhile back. Handy when you can find a way to use it instead of apply.

Answer (score 3):

Building on the great answer by @John Colby, we can get rid of the apply step and speed it up quite a bit (about 20x):

```
# Create a bigger test set 
A <- c(1, NA, NA, 4, NA, 7, NA, NA, NA, NA)
B <- c(NA, 2, NA, NA, 5, NA, 8, NA, 11, NA)
C <- c(NA, NA, 3, NA, NA, NA, NA, 9, NA, 12)
n=1e6; test_df = data.frame(A=rep(A, len=n), B=rep(B, len=n), C=rep(C, len=n))

# John Colby's method, 9.66 secs
system.time({
  df1 = with(test_df, cbind(A[1:(length(A)-2)], B[2:(length(B)-1)], C[3:length(C)]))
  df1 = data.frame(df1[!apply(df1, 1, function(x) all(is.na(x))), ])
  colnames(df1) = c('A', 'B', 'C')
})

# My method, 0.48 secs
system.time({
  df2 = with(test_df, data.frame(A=A[1:(length(A)-2)], B=B[2:(length(B)-1)], C=C[3:length(C)]))
  df2 = df2[is.finite(with(df2, A|B|C)),]
  row.names(df2) <- NULL
})

identical(df1, df2) # TRUE
```

...The trick here is that `A|B|C` is only `NA` if all values are `NA`. This turns out to be much faster than calling `all(is.na(x))` on each row of a matrix using `apply`.

**EDIT** @John has a different approach that also speeds it up. I added some code to turn the result into a data.frame with correct names and timed it. It seems to be pretty much the same speed as my solution.

```
# John's method, 0.50 secs
system.time({
  test_m = with(test_df, cbind(A[1:(length(A)-2)], B[2:(length(B)-1)], C[3:length(C)]))
  test_m[is.na(test_m)] <- -1
  test_m <- test_m[rowSums(test_m) > -3,]
  test_m[test_m == -1] <- NA
  df3 <- data.frame(test_m)
  colnames(df3) = c('A', 'B', 'C')
})

identical(df1, df3) # TRUE
```

**EDIT AGAIN** ...and @John Colby's updated answer is even faster!

```
# John Colby's method, 0.39 secs
system.time({
  df4 = with(test_df, cbind(A[1:(length(A)-2)], B[2:(length(B)-1)], C[3:length(C)]))
  df4 = data.frame(df4[rowSums(is.na(df4)) != ncol(df4), ])
  colnames(df4) = c('A', 'B', 'C')
})

identical(df1, df4) # TRUE
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of the system.time function, but I am going to get a lot of great use out of it! Thanks for this and for the suggested method.

Answer (score 2):

So your question was just about moving up without a loop.  So apparently you solved the first step already.

```
> test_m <- with( test_df, cbind(A[1:(length(A)-2)], B[2:(length(B)-1)], C[3:length(C)]) )
> test_m
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]   NA   NA   NA
[3,]   NA   NA   NA
[4,]    4    5   NA
[5,]   NA   NA   NA
[6,]    7    8    9
[7,]   NA   NA   NA
[8,]   NA   11   12
```

Which is now a matrix.  You can easily eliminate the rows for which there is no data point now without a loop.  If you want it back to a data.frame then you could use a different method but this one will run the fastest for a large mount of data.  I like to just make the NA's an impossible value... perhaps -1 but you'll know best for your data... perhaps -pi.

```
test_m[is.na(test_m)] <- -1
```

And now just select the rows for a property of those impossible numbers

```
test_m <- test_m[rowSums(test_m) > -3,]
```

And, if you want you can put the NA's back.

```
test_m[test_m == -1] <- NA
test_m
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    4    5   NA
[3,]    7    8    9
[4,]   NA   11   12
```

There's no loop (`for` or `apply`) and the one function applied across rows of the matrix is specially optimized and runs very fast (rowSums).

Comment: Thank you, John. The method for moving into and out of NA's that you suggested here will surely come in useful to me in the future.